# How to validate Personal Geodatabase against XML schema?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, xml, personal-geodatabase

Is there a tool in ArcGIS ModelBuilder which can validate a personal geodatabase and an XML schema to give out an report saying if the gdb is validated or not?

Comment: According to my knowledge the tool does not exists...but you can post this to ArcGIS Ideas..may be they will implement this idea..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a method to use [X-Ray for ArcCatalog](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9ea218ff575f4a5195e01a2cae03a0ae) to do what you want.

It is not something that I have used personally so I am going on information in a [GeoNet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/61175) that says:

> I would suggest you use X-Ray to validate your XML workspace before
>   attempting to import it.  You'll find the Validate tool under theTools
>   dropdown.  The validate tool will check your XML workspace document
>   and give you a report of the errors.